# How to Get HTML tag's Jquery Selector to string value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

I want to get HTML tag's jQuery selector to a string value

All of HTML document tags value.

How to get there?

ex)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contents">
    <p class="txt_1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p class="txt_2">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
        it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    <p class="txt_3">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

export)

div.contents 
p.txt_1 
p.txt_2 
p.txt_3

Comment: please explain more what you want exactly ?

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL probably to add all elements used with their class in to an array? That's what I gathered

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/48cnko9s/

Comment: I think you want to select the paragraph and display its value.you can do it by $(p.text_1).text() or you can use $(p[class="text_1"]).text() . if not please state clearly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery selector `$(element)` like this,

Note: `$('p[class^="txt_"]')` This selects the `p` elements having class start with `txt_`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var allContent = $('p[class^="txt_"]');
  console.log(allContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contents">
    <p class="txt_1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <p class="txt_2">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
        it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
    <p class="txt_3">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body *').get().map(function(v){
    var line = v.tagName.toLowerCase() + '.' + (v.getAttribute('class') || '');
    return line.replace(/[\.\s]+$/, '');
});
```

without jquery

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body *'), function(v){
    var line = v.tagName.toLowerCase() + '.' + (v.getAttribute('class') || '');
    return line.replace(/[\.\s]+$/, '');
});
```

1. Get all DOM Nodes by selecting body * (asterisk matches all nodes)
2. Optional: call get method on jquery object to return a bare array
3. run map on the array to transform its nodes to the desired string
4. concat the line by getting the tagName and appending the className separated with a .
5. replace "." and "\s" (whitespace) characters at the end of the string to represent tags without class without a dot at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get string text value using class. like
$('.txt_1').text();
This is for one p tag text by p tag class

$('.contents p').text()
This is for all p tags that are in the div